# CakePHP how to generate its password external

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, cakephp, hash

CakePHP how to generate its password external

I am used to use php, and I had an app that need to integrate with CakePHP.

Basically I am trying create a Login Form which can use the same hash & encryption method of CakePHP.

I look into several files like SecurityComponent and AuthComponent of cake PHP and this is what I derive

```
$string = "demopassw0rd";
$type = null;
$salt = "mySALT";

$string = $salt . "demo1234";

$stringnew = sha1($string);
echo md5($stringnew);

echo "    SPACES        ";

$stringnew2 = bin2hex(mhash(MHASH_SHA256, $string));
echo md5($stringnew2);


//Below is the real code.

                if ($salt) {
                        if (is_string($salt)) {
                                $string = $salt . $string;
                        } else {
                                $string = $salt . $string;
                        }
                }

                if (empty($type)) {
                        $type = $hashType;
                }
                $type = strtolower($type);

                if ($type == 'sha1' || $type == null) {
                        if (function_exists('sha1')) {
                                $return = sha1($string);
                                return $return;
                        }
                        $type = 'sha256';
                }

                if ($type == 'sha256' && function_exists('mhash')) {
                        return bin2hex(mhash(MHASH_SHA256, $string));
                }
```

Using the above method that was extracted from cake php, I fail to retrieve the same password hash that was stored in mysql.

I am trying to create a hash method so I can create another login form that is not cakephp framework and able use the same login table as my cake php software that reside in the same server.

```
 * The level of CakePHP security.
 */
        Configure::write('Security.level', 'medium');

/**
 * A random string used in security hashing methods.
 */
        Configure::write('Security.salt', 'mySALT');

/**
 * A random numeric string (digits only) used to encrypt/decrypt strings.
 */
        Configure::write('Security.cipherSeed', '65986349865349087509054352724');
```

How do I make use of the config above to make my own hash method that can hash my input string to the same as what I stored in mysql using cakephp

I interpreted cake php hashing method for the configuration above is

Firstly

```
$salt . $string to form a $string value

then sha1($string) and then md5($string)

or bin2hex with the sha264 ($string) and then md5(string)
```

but both I tried and fail to get the same hash as cake php

Comment: Why making your life hard? Use the existing class. Classes are portable and callable/usable from the outside as well: `require ....; $object = new ...;`. No need to hack sth together on your own. That can only go wrong.

Comment: @mark thanks for the idea. but I not sure how to use the class :) but i will explore it

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to call a webservice in your cake app.. with that in mind you can call it from any language or app... with this you are using the mechanics of cake like mark said "use the existing class" but in another form...